# How to setup RHC for openshift? I encountered: `can't satisfy 'highline (~> 1.6.11)', already activated 'highline-1.7.1' (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, openshift-client-tools

I need to use openshift to deploy a web application and modify files for database connection and I install the RHC. But it cannot be setup. I installed rbenv, but don't really know how to use. My mac was bought 1 week. Basically, not many softwares are installed. The complete error message is as follows:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1206:in `block in activate_dependencies': can't satisfy 'highline (~> 1.6.11)', already activated 'highline-1.7.1' (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1198:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1198:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1180:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:48:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rhc:22:in `<main>'
```

Could anyone or any person help me solve this problem and let me setup RHC properly?

Answer (score 5):

You need to update gem.

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update

sudo update_rubygems

sudo gem install rhc
```